Significance in multiple regression but not in single regression
I first run a multiple regression: y ~ a + b + x and find both a and b to be significant (p<0.005).
Then for each subgroup of $a = a_1, a_2, ...., a_n$, I run y ~ b + x and find b not significant. How could this be happening? I understand the opposite (significant in single regression but not in multiple) is quite often.

I have read this Q&A but I don't understand think collinearity can fully explain this. If a and b are collinear, how could they both have such small p-values?
The other referenced Q&As are also not exactly the same as this one. The other ones are about adding additional variables (apart from a and b) making something changing from non-significant to significant but my question does not involve additional variables.

Is a a categorical variable, something like dog/cat/horse/alligator, with you running separate regressions for the dogs, then the cats, then the horses, then the gators?

For more posts about this FAQ, see this site search

a is integer, but only takes 1-10. @Dave

When you run the stratified models, each model has many fewer data, so you have less power.  It's probably that simple.  Your full model assumes the associations w/ b & w/ x are straight lines & are parallel w/i the levels of a.  If you don't believe that, or just want to check, there are better ways than stratified models (eg, interaction).

Re your edit: Your question concerns what happens to the significance in regression when adding variable $a$ after regressing on $b$ or vice versa.  We have threads about all possible ways in which significance can change when adding or deleting explanatory variables: please search on regression significant not.

The main issue here is that you are running models over subsets of the data.  Each subset necessarily has many fewer data than the whole dataset and thus, much less statistical power to find a significant result.  If you look at the simulated example below, coded in R, you can see that the entire dataset has N=60 data (and 53 residual degrees of freedom), but the subset has only 10 data (8 df).  (Note that I dropped X for simplicity; the relevant issues are the same whether it's there or not.)
set.seed(3670)
a = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:6], each=10))
b = runif(60, min=0, max=10)
y = as.numeric(a) + 0.15*b + rnorm(60, mean=0, sd=1)

m = lm(y~a+b)
summary(m)
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  1.21605    0.39276   3.096  0.00313 ** 
# aB           1.07444    0.40629   2.645  0.01074 *  
# aC           2.20648    0.40704   5.421 1.48e-06 ***
# aD           2.80727    0.40426   6.944 5.55e-09 ***
# aE           3.67393    0.42184   8.709 8.38e-12 ***
# aF           4.47946    0.40416  11.083 2.04e-15 ***
# b            0.13269    0.04673   2.839  0.00640 ** 
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.9037 on 53 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7612,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7342 
# F-statistic: 28.16 on 6 and 53 DF,  p-value: 7.653e-15

summary(lm(y~b, subset=a=="A"))
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept)   0.5521     0.7772   0.710   0.4977  
# b             0.2479     0.1240   1.999   0.0806 .
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.9658 on 8 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.3332,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.2499 
# F-statistic: 3.998 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.08059

A bigger issue is that this follow-up analysis doesn't make any sense.  When you fit a model such as y~a+b, you are assuming that the relationship between b ans y is the same at all levels of a.  The slope of that relationship is identical by design.  It doesn't make a lot of sense to turn around and ask if the relationships are significant in each individual case—they are all the same so they are all equally significant.  If you are wondering if the slopes are the same, then you need to fit a model with an interaction between a and b.  The test of that interaction will tell you if you have sufficient evidence to believe the slopes differ.
mi = lm(y~a*b)
summary(mi)
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  0.55205    0.72896   0.757  0.45256    
# aB           2.64432    0.97428   2.714  0.00920 ** 
# aC           2.77383    0.91644   3.027  0.00397 ** 
# aD           3.02945    1.05292   2.877  0.00597 ** 
# aE           4.66757    0.87909   5.310 2.79e-06 ***
# aF           4.86571    0.99360   4.897 1.14e-05 ***
# b            0.24785    0.11626   2.132  0.03817 *  
# aB:b        -0.30105    0.16630  -1.810  0.07651 .  
# aC:b        -0.09473    0.15376  -0.616  0.54074    
# aD:b        -0.03571    0.17185  -0.208  0.83628    
# aE:b        -0.21887    0.17114  -1.279  0.20708    
# aF:b        -0.06630    0.15839  -0.419  0.67740    
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.9058 on 48 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7827,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7329 
# F-statistic: 15.72 on 11 and 48 DF,  p-value: 2.16e-12

anova(m, mi)
# Analysis of Variance Table
# 
# Model 1: y ~ a + b
# Model 2: y ~ a * b
#   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
# 1     53 43.283                           
# 2     48 39.387  5    3.8968 0.9498 0.4578

In this case, we do not have sufficient evidence to think the slopes differ depending on which level of a you are talking about (not coincidentally, there isn't an interaction in the way I simulated the data).
For the sake of providing a more complete answer, we can pretend the interaction was significant and it was clear that the slopes differ.  In that case, you might want to have tests of the slopes in each level of a.  The first thing to realize is that the 'main effect' of a variable that is a constituent of an interaction is the estimate of the relationship between that variable and the response when the other constituent variable is exactly equal to $0$ or is at its reference level.  That is, in the output from the interaction model, "b  0.24785  0.11626...  0.03817 *", gives us the slope, SE, and p-value of the association between b and y when a is at its reference level (A).  If we compare that to the simple regression model above in which we examined the relationship between b and y when a equals A, we see that they are the same (0.2479, and 0.24785).  What differs is the SE's and the p-values (0.1240 vs. 0.11626, and 0.0806 vs. 0.03817, respectively).  The reason is that the interaction model uses all of the data.  Armed with this insight, the simplest way to get a test of b at each level of a is to reset the reference level of a and rerun the interaction model.  At no point do you run simple regressions on the various subsets of the data.
